# How to recover a deleted file from a remote server?

Tags: command-line, files, trash

I deleted a file from a remote server and have no idea how to recover that. I don't have access to the system and can only use it through the terminal(via ssh).

Comment: what you mean you can only use it through the terminal. Please be more specific.

Comment: I mean I can only access it via ssh

Comment: Ask the server admin to restore the file from backup.

Comment: I know that but is there a way that I can do it myself?

Comment: Are you root / sudo ?

Comment: No, I can not use sudo commands

Comment: Then you can not and @SorenA's comment applies.

Comment: For sudo users how can do the same?